# hash collision chance using a 5 chars hash made of a-z A-Z and 0-9 (62 chars total)

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

What is the chance for collision or resistance of a hash made out of 5 chars randomly picked from this sets `a-z A-Z` and `0-9` (62 chars total).

Also, what is total amount of combinations without collision that I can get, AFAIK :

$62^5 = 916.132.832$

Thank you.

Comment: See [_Birthday problem for cryptographic hashing, 101_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555), which derives likelihood of collision $p_n$ after $n$ draws among $k$ values, and various related approximations.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed $62^5 = 916\,132\,832$ possible hashes in that syntax.  If they are uniformly distributed, then the [standard birthday paradox](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68203) applies to the probability of a collision in $n$ independent choices of $k$ possible hashes.  For $n < \sqrt{k}/4$, the probability of collision is between $(n - 1)^2/(4k)$ and $n^2/k$.  For example, among 10 000 hashes, the probability of a collision is at least $$\frac{9\,999^2}{4\cdot916\,132\,832} > 2.7\%,$$ and at most $$\frac{10\,000^2}{916\,132\,832} < 11\%.$$

Of course, if these are hashes from a fixed public hash function like SHAKE128-30 (add two more characters to your alphabet like the base64 `+` and `-` to make the numbers work out), it is easy for an adversary to spend the energy to compute a few tens of thousands of hashes *offline* without interacting with you in order to find a collision with high probability.  The lower bound on the collision probability gives a guarantee on the adversary's chance of success after a certain amount of work.

So with numbers as small as this, not much can be said about fixed public hash functions.  On the other hand, this analysis remains relevant for a *secret* hash function, a pseudorandom function family (PRF), like SipHash or KMAC128 or keyed BLAKE2 under a *secret* key not known to the adversary.